# Combining Spring's JPA Auditor with JPA Versioning with Hibernate @Generated(GenerationTime.ALWAYS) results in broken UPDATE queries

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

For reference, this is an example entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "example")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Example {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "rep_firm_id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id;

  @Column(name = "created_time", nullable = false, updatable = false)
  @CreatedDate
  private OffsetDateTime createdTime;

  @Column(name = "modified_time")
  @LastModifiedDate
  private OffsetDateTime modifiedTime;

  @Column(name = "xmin")
  @Version
  @Generated(GenerationTime.ALWAYS)
  private int version;
}
```

If I comment out the @EntityListeners annotation, then the version property works as expected, i.e., UPDATE queries have the following: UPDATE example SET foo = bla WHERE xmin = version

If I comment out the @Version annotation, then the UPDATE queries don't have the WHERE xmin = version, but they do have UPDATE example SET foo bla, modified_time = time

If I combine the 2, I get a VERY weird behavior, and I haven't figured out the cause:

UPDATE example SET foo bla, modified_time = time WHERE xmin = versionPlusOne

Essentially, it uses the "next version" on the WHERE clause instead of the "previous version", but only if auditing is enabled on the entity.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think it s linked to your annotations. I read on the doc that GenerationTime.ALWAYS updates the entity at both time insert and update. In the case of GenerationTime.ALWAYS, the property should not be insertable and updatable.
And at the same time you use @Version which is going to be updated at each change

Comment: If I remove the Entity Listener, it works fine, i.e., update clauses have "previous version" in the WHERE xmin = ?, but with the Entity Listener, it has "next version" in the WHERE xmin = ? (which causes ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException exceptions due to there being no rows to update with the "next version")